# Is it possible to only retrieve a list of keys from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, nosql

I have a node in this form:

```
index
   $categoryId
     $productId
```

I wish to retrieve primarily a list of the keys of `index`, thus an object filled with all the available `$categoryId` in index.

Is there a way to retrieve this list in Firebase? I am assuming that it is more efficient to retrieve a list of keys than a list with all the data from `$categoryId`.

I understand that an alternative way is to maintain an index list of all the categories, but this requires some more coding (when categories get edited and deleted).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You can use the [shallow keys option](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-param-shallow) in the REST API, but indexing  is preferred.**

**[Plnker demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/doAuTkcH8DLakKB8adzT?p=preview)**

```
fetch('<my-firebase-app>/category/.json?shallow=true')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then((data) => console.log(data)) // prints only keys under category
```

Unfortunately, there's no solution in the realtime SDKs. But, I would recommend structuring your data to avoid having to use the REST API. Try storing an index of `$categoryId` in your Firebase database. I know this is extra code, but it's usually a one-liner.

```
{
  "lookupCategory": {
    "category_one": true,
    "category_two": true,
    "category_three": true,
    "category_four": true,
    "category_five": true
  }
}
```

With this index, you can just do a realtime listen, or a `.once()` if preferred.

```
var ref = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>/lookupCategory');
ref.on('value', (snap) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Makes sense. Is this something you are working on at Firebase, or is it not relevant?

Comment: It is relevant, but I don't have an update right now. Hope this works for you in the mean time.

Comment: @DavidEast please answer my question of Firebase here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646255/retrieve-all-child-value-to-a-label-in-table-view-cell thanks in advance