# Retrieve all child value to a label in table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve all the child values of "Cake" to cake Rate Label.
I am trying to retrieve but i can not arrange properly code and also i am entry level to ios.

**Firebase Structure**

[image]

**ViewController**

[image]

**TestTableViewCell**

```
import UIKit
class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var cakeImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var cakeEngLabs: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cakeUrLabs: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cakeRateLabs: UILabel!

}
```

*TestTableViewController**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var cakeTableView: UITableView!

var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


struct Cake {
  let cakeEngNames: String
  let cakeUrNames: String
  let cakeImages: UIImage
  var cakeRates: String
}


var cakes = [Cake(cakeEngNames: "almond Cake", cakeUrNames: "badam cake",     cakeImages: UIImage(named:"Maru")!, cakeRates: ""),

         Cake(cakeEngNames: "Jelly Cake", cakeUrNames: "jeli ka cake", cakeImages: UIImage(named:"spices")!, cakeRates: ""),

         Cake(cakeEngNames: "Jelly Cake", cakeUrNames: "jeli ka cake", cakeImages: UIImage(named:"spices")!, cakeRates: ""),

         Cake(cakeEngNames: "Jelly Cake", cakeUrNames: "jeli ka cake", cakeImages: UIImage(named:"spices")!, cakeRates: "")]




override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let AlmondSnap = ref.child("Hyderabad").child("Bakery").child("Cake")
AlmondSnap.observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let almondRate = snapshot.value as! String
        self.cakes[].cakeRates = almondRate

        print("\(almondRate)")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
})
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return self.cakes.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell

cell.cakeImage.image = self.cakes[indexPath.row].cakeImages
cell.cakeEngLabs.text = self.cakes[indexPath.row].cakeEngNames
cell.cakeUrLabs.text = self.cakes[indexPath.row].cakeUrNames
cell.cakeRateLabs.text = self.cakes[indexPath.row].cakeRates
return cell
}
}
```

Comment: I can't quite tell what you're asking here. What happens when you run the code you have now? What would you like to happen?

Comment: i want to retrieve all the child value of 'Cake' to ckae array in Testtabnleviewcontroller so it can appear in cakreratelabel in viewcopntroller

Comment: At the moment, your cakes are in an array `var cakes`. Are you saying that instead of populating this array with four hard-coded cakes, you want to retrieve it from a database instead?

Comment: yes sir  quit right

Comment: only in cakeRates i want to populate all the cake values successively from firebase

Comment: @Xcodian If you want all cake object then you need to observe for `Hyderabad` not `Karachi` and you need to add reference only to child `.child("Cake")`.

Comment: @NiravD updated the question sir,

Comment: Hi, try changing this `let almondRate = snapshot.value as! String` to this `if let almondRate = snapshot.value as? [String] { ... }`

Comment: @Xcodian What is the output of `print(snapshot.value)`?

Comment: @AlissonEnz conasole : Firetest [1525 ] < Warning > [ Firebase / Analytics ] [ I - ACS020001 ] Failed to get Instance ID : Error Domain = com . firebase . iid Code = - 34018 " ( null ) "

Comment: @NiravD  when i commented ' self.cakes[].cakeRates = almondRate ' and put 'print(snapshot.value!) ' this prints all things in view controller that is Eng name and Ur name but does not get child values from "Cake" to Cake rate label in view controller ... but when i uncomment the 'self.cakes[].cakeRates = almondRate ' it gives error ' cannot subscript a value of type '[TestTableViewController.Cake]' with an index of type '()' '

Comment: @Xcodian Is your child ref path is correct? 
`let AlmondSnap = ref.child("Hyderabad").child("Bakery").child("Cake")
AlmondSnap.observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in {}` I'm taking about this ref `print(snapshot.value!)` in above block.

Comment: @NiravD yes sir everything is same and this prints every thing but not gets children of Cake to cake rate label

Comment: @Xcodian Then what is the console log of `print(snapshot.value!)`

Comment: @NiravD sir here is the conasole : Firetest [1525 ] < Warning > [ Firebase / Analytics ] [ I - ACS020001 ] Failed to get Instance ID : Error Domain = com . firebase . iid Code = - 34018 " ( null ) "

Comment: @Xcodian Check that your reference is correct.

Comment: @NiravD yes sir reference is correct

Comment: @NiravD when i commented ' self.cakes[].cakeRates = almondRate ' and put 'print(snapshot.value!) ' this prints all things in view controller that is Eng name and Ur name but does not get child values from "Cake" to Cake rate label in view controller ... but when i uncomment the 'self.cakes[].cakeRates = almondRate ' it gives error ' cannot subscript a value of type '[TestTableViewController.Cake]' with an index of type '()' '

Comment: @Xcodian It's obvious that 'self.cakes[].cakeRates = almondRate` this will give you error because cakes is array so you need to access one of its object using subscript [0] or [1] or any index of array.

Comment: yes sir, but i want to access all of them to a label what should i do that

Comment: i have tried to access by [0] and [1] explicitly instead of all in one but that also gives error

Comment: i also tried just like self.cakes[0].cakeRates = almondRate and self.cakes[1].cakeRates = almondRate and self.cakes[2].cakeRates = almondRate onwards but it gives error

Comment: @NiravD I am awaiting for your answer sir,

Comment: @Xcodian I don't have much experience with Firebase, if your reference is correct then you will get child from cakes but you are not getting proper data currently. Try once `print(snapshot.children)` what is the log for this one.

Comment: ok sir i am trying to set out

Comment: There's a very simple solution but there's also question; are the child node keys of Cake (Almond_Cake, Black_Forest_Cake etc) always the same or do they vary? i.e. is there sometimes a Pound_Cake node and sometimes not Also, please post your Firebase structure as text, no images.

Comment: @Xcodian Have you checked with `print(snapshot.children)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on comments, as you said that you only need cakename and its rate to fill in the table. Other then that is static (if not than please go for a structure and answer suggested by @dstepan) .. So here is how you can fill up your data in tableview.

```
   var cakes = [Cake]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let almondSnap = ref.child("Hyderabad").child("Bakery").child("Cake")
        almondSnap.observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.hasChildren(){
                for snap in snapshot.children {
                   // snap.key produces name of cake
                   // snap.value produces rate of cake

                    if let node = snap as? FIRDataSnapshot, let rate = node.value as? Int {
                        self.cakes.append(Cake(cakeEngNames: node.key,
                                          cakeUrNames: "badam cake",
                                          cakeImages: UIImage(named:"Maru")!,
                                          cakeRates: String(rate)))
                    }
                }
                self.cakeTableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you store the all values in NSMutableArray use this**

```
cell.cakeRateLbl.text = “Almon Cake Rate :\(self.cakesArray[0].objectForKey(“Hyderabad”).objectAtIndex(0).objectForKey(“Bakery”).ObjectAtIndex(0).objectForKey(“Cake”).objectAtIndex(0).valueForKey(“Almon_Cake”) as! Int)\nAzna Mental Cake Rate :\(self.cakesArray[0].objectForKey(“Hyderabad”).objectAtIndex(0).objectForKey(“Bakery”).ObjectAtIndex(0).objectForKey(“Cake”).objectAtIndex(0).valueForKey(“Azna_Mental_Cake”) as! Int)\nBlack Forest Cake Rate :\(self.cakesArray[0].objectForKey(“Hyderabad”).objectAtIndex(0).objectForKey(“Bakery”).ObjectAtIndex(0).objectForKey(“Cake”).objectAtIndex(0).valueForKey(“Black_Forest_Cake”) as! Int)”
```

**Or you can try this**

```
cell.cakeRateLbl.text = “Almon Cake Rate :\(self.cakes[indexpath.row].Almond_Cake)\nAzna Mental Cake Rate :\(self.cakes[indexpath.row].Azna_Mental_Cake)\nBlack Forest Cake Rate :\(self.cakes[indexpath.row].Black_Forest_Cake)”
```

Comment: Is this an answer? If so, can you explain it and also format so it's readable?

Comment: For getting all price details in single Label initially we need to get all the values in string swift convert AnyObject into string easily for example we need to get the price for Almon Cake simply` let almonCakePirce = "\(self.cakesArray[0].objectForKey(“Hyderabad”).objectAtIndex(0).objectForKey(“Bakery”).ObjectAtIndex(0).objectForKey(“Cake”).objectAtIndex(0).valueForKey(“Azna_Mental_Cake”) as! Int)" `now integer converted into string if we need to add another one value to that string means  add "\n" between the strings

Comment: @GaneshManickam there are a lot of errors please help me to improve these errors & warnings for separation of statements

Answer (score 0):

As currently constructed, you could access your `Cake` node like below:

```
var cakes: [Cake] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let AlmondSnap = ref.child("Hyderabad").child("Bakery").child("Cake")

    AlmondSnap.observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for item in snapshot.children {

           if let cakeFromDatabase = item as? FIRDataSnapshot {

                let cake = Cake()

                cake.cakeRates = cakeFromDatabase.value // for "Almond_Cake" this will be 800

                cakes.append(cake)

            }

        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

However, you could probably benefit from making a couple of design changes to your current approach, based on what I'm seeing.

You database structure should probably be

```
dgrproject-ac0e7
-- Hyderabad
    -- Bakery
        -- Cakes
            -- id1
                -- name: Almond Cake
                -- rate: 800
```

and so on.

Then, in your code, you could do the following

```
var cakes: [Cake] = [] {
    didSet {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let AlmondSnap = ref.child("Hyderabad").child("Bakery").child("Cake")

    AlmondSnap.observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let allCakes = []

        for item in snapshot.children {

            if let cakeFromDatabase = item as? FIRDataSnapshot {

                let cake = Cake()

                cake.cakeEngNames = cakeFromDatabase["name"] as? String
                cake.cakeRates = cakeFromDatabase["rate"] as? Int

                allCakes.append(cake)

            }

        }

        cakes = allCakes
    })
}
```

Adding `didSet` to your cakes array will now automatically refresh the tableView whenever you set `cakes`. This cleans up the code a bit inside your completion handler for the firebase call. We also create an `allCakes` array so that we aren't appending a new `Cake` object to `cakes` and causing the table view to be reloaded potentially hundreds of times as the dataset grows.

Hope this helps!